# Como realizar un factorial para mi calculadora

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una calculadora científica. Esta calculadora tiene varias funciones matemáticas para el número ingresado. Por ejemplo, en este código se calcula la raiz cuadrada:

```
if (e.getSource() == boton[11]) {
    if (!entrada.equals("") && !entrada.equals("0")) {
        double valor = Double.parseDouble(entrada);
        valor = Math.sqrt(valor);
        entrada = "" + valor;
    }
}
```

Lo que necesito es mostrar el resultado del cálculo del factorial en el siguiente código:

```
if( e.getSource() == boton[3]) {
    double valor = Double.parseDouble(entrada); 
    //qué hacer
}
```

¿Alguien me ayudaría por favor?

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio Ely. ¿Cuál es tu problema específico: crear un método que devuelva el factorial de un número entero x o hacer que un botón pueda llamar a dicho método para mostrarlo en tu calculadora?

Comment: hacer que el boton lo llame

Comment: Ok, entonces te recomiendo que por favor edites la pregunta y muestres el código relevante de tu aplicación (no todo el código) para poder ayudarte. Esto es: el código de tu método `factorial`, el código de tu botón y el código donde le estás agregando la funcionalidad al botón.

Comment: Como por ejemplo, en este boton if (e.getSource() == boton[11]) {
   if (!entrada.equals("") && !entrada.equals("0")) {
    double valor = Double.parseDouble(entrada);
    valor = Math.sqrt(valor);
    entrada = "" + valor;
   }
  }  estoy haciendo la raiz cuadrada, asi como en este

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que tienes un método llamado `factorial` definido de la siguiente manera (o similar):

```
private long factorial(long n) {
    /* código del método factorial */
}
```

Puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
if( e.getSource() == boton[3]) {
    long valor = Long.parseLong(entrada);
    entrada = String.valueOf(factorial(valor));
}
```

Comment: Creo que esta es la única respuesta a la pregunta, ya que el usuario menciona que tiene el problema para invocar al método desde el botón, tema que no se toca en ninguna otra

Answer (score 1):

> Recordando que el factorial de un número es el resultado que se
>   obtiene de multiplicar dicho número por el anterior y así
>   sucesivamente hasta llegar a uno.

Mi respuesta es utilizando la recursividad y valor de retorno long para evitar desbordamientos.

```
long factorial(int x) {
    return (x == 0) ?  1 : x * factorial(x-1);
}
```

Enlace de interés: [Enlace](https://geekytheory.com/que-es-la-recursividad/)

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tenia al invocar al metodo desde su boton, no espeficicamente con el metodo factorial

Answer (score 0):

> Quizás esto te pueda ayudar:

```
    public int factorial(int numero){
      int factorial=1;
      for(int i=1,i<=numero;i++){
        factorial=i*factorial;
      }
      return factorial;
    }
```

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tenia al invocar al metodo desde su boton, no espeficicamente con el metodo factorial

Answer (score 0):

Aportando un granito de arena usando recursividad:

```
public int factorial(int numero)
{
   int resultado;
   if(numero==0 || numero==1)
     return 1;

   resultado = factorial(numero-1) * numero;
   return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tenia al invocar al metodo desde su boton, no espeficicamente con el metodo factorial